# Meaning of "The quit vetting politicians a long time ago"

Tags: politics

people! Can you help with this?

**MAN 1:** I'm not sure I'll withstand the vetting.

**MAN 2:** They quit vetting politicians a long time ago. Let's go figure out the how.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It also sounds to me like there's a typo, I think it probably reads "*They* quit vetting. . ." If you're asking about the meaning of "vetting," it just means to examine critically.

Comment: Thanks, Riley! So, the person wrote this wrongly? There's no sense at all?

Comment: "The quit vetting politicians. . ." definitely does not make sense. I'm almost certain it ought to be "They quit vetting . . ." I'm assuming that MAN 1 is some sort of politician worried about legal trouble or something from his past, and MAN 2 is trying to assure him that everything will be okay.

Comment: Please don't do that. Please at least check your spelling… "The quit…"? Really? If you’re quoting an author, please provide citations. Else, please tell us whether the example phrases were contrived, or what?
As posted, you seem to be quoting part of the script of a play or some other dialogue. Either way, the thing is flawed. Broadly, it fails when MAN 2 takes the stage.
“They quit vetting politicians a long time ago” is one thing. “Let's go figure out the how…” means exactly what, please?
Because you posted only what you chose, no-one could say whether “the person wrote this wrongly…”

Answer (score 0):

the verb quit as an action verb is followed by another verb in the gerund form.

- To quit smoking
- To quit working
- To quit vetting

in short, to quit doing something.

Answer (score -1):

"To vet" means to investigate the past of a person, usually as preparation for employment.  Arrest history, employment history, any past behavior that might affect the person's ability to perform the job would be investigated.

So the conversation is a commentary on the fact that nowadays, they seem to let anyone become a politician and be elected to office, and their past behavior seems to matter little.

Far be it from me to mention any names...